# Justify Rotated SVG Text Within Container

Tags: html, css, svg

I'd like to get a vertically-resizable element showing some SVG text elements justified, one to the top and one to the bottom. The element also has rotated text, which may be complicating my attempted solutions.

https://codepen.io/elsewhere_/pen/abOBapZ

The intended behavior of the above pen would be that the element with text "Left" is justified to the bottom of the container always (the "left" side if you angle your head to read the text), and similarly the element with the text "Right" would be justified to the top of the container always.

The actual behavior is that the elements remain at some constant offset from the center of the container.

This is true at the default element size due to me playing with transform:translate styling until that worked, but this isn't a proper way to go about getting a generalized solution for any height of the container. My problem is that I don't know what is the proper approach here. I have seen similar questions to this, but solutions provided didn't appear to work in my specific case, e.g. text-anchor, justify-content, using percentage (%) css units to reference the container, and so on.

Specifically for using percentage, I'm confused as to what it is referencing to. I believe I set up the element to reference its container's size by setting "position:absolute", but what specifically is being referenced? The container's width for x offsets? Its height for y offsets? Does the rotation of the text muddle the math here (e.g. flip the x and y axes for this calculation)?

And even if I was using percentage properly, it's not the behavior I want ideally. The text elements should justify with a constant padding margin against the top and bottom of the container, not a percentage padding margin (as they will visually scale away from the edge at very large container heights).

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0px; 
  width: 32px;
  height: 80px;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 80" height="100%" width="100%" style="position:absolute; pointer-events:none;">
  <text style="transform-origin: center; 
 transform:rotate(-90deg) translate(18px, 40px);" fill="red" >Right</text>
 <text text-anchor="left" style="transform-origin: center; 
 transform:rotate(-90deg) translate(-20px, 40px);" fill="red" >Left</text>
</svg>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use 2 different svg instead of 1 with 2 'children' ? It would make the stuff more simple and more 'html valid'

Comment: Yes, there's no specific reason they're in the same SVG. But there would still be the task of justifying the child elements. Would splitting up the text into separate svg elements afford some layout that could make that possible?

Comment: Definitively yes ;) Your svg's 'children' are fixed to the viewBox of the svg so you can't use layout utilities like `flexbox`.

Comment: Ah, right you are. I was trying to use flex earlier but hadn't set it up properly. I split everything into multiple flex elements, and it seems to have achieved the effect I was looking for (and a bit more beyond what I stated here for my specific application: https://codepen.io/elsewhere_/pen/QWbGzaR). Should be resolved, then.